# Does the size parameter for Cordova's requestFileSystem method do anything?

Tags: file, cordova

Cordova provides the following api for requesting a file system:

```
window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback, errorCallback)
```

The Cordova documentation states:

> **size**: indicates how much storage space, in bytes, the application expects to need

However all their examples show size set to 0 as in:

> window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, onError);

I don't seem to run into errors when I set size to 0 yet use space on the filesystem. Does the size actually have any meaning when the platform is ios or android or is it a relic of the html5 spec and is ignored for the mobile device platforms.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think that "size"parameter is for the app (you make) to know if you have space enough to accomplish your/apps needs. You need 10GB, so you ask to the device for.. did you get it?, ok play! didn't get it... message to user "you need to buy a new machine" You say to requestFileSystem that you need only 1MB size, there is not problem if you use 5GB but you are unsecure, your app can crash, that's it.</strike>

I could not create files bigger than 33 characteres (more or less) when I tested with size 0.